# Tensorflow RNN stuck at high cost

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, recurrent-neural-network

The following RNN model decreases the loss for the first one or two epochs and then fluctuates around the cost of 6. This seems like the model is so random and not learning at all. I varied the learning rate from 0.1 to 0.0001 and it didn't help. The data is fed with an input pipeline, which worked fine with other models, so the functions that extract the label and images are not presented here. I have looked at this for so many times but still couldn't find what's wrong with it. Here's the code:

```
n_steps = 224
n_inputs = 224
learning_rate = 0.00015
batch_size = 256 # n_neurons
epochs = 100
num_batch = int(len(trainnames)/batch_size)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# TRAIN QUEUE
train_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(len(trainnames)*1.5, 0, [tf.string, tf.float32], shapes=[[],[num_labels,]])

enqueue_train = train_queue.enqueue_many([trainnames, train_label])

train_image, train_image_label = train_queue.dequeue()

train_image = read_image_file(train_image)

train_batch, train_label_batch = tf.train.batch(
    [train_image, train_image_label],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_threads=1,
    capacity=10*batch_size,
    enqueue_many=False,
    shapes=[[224,224], [num_labels,]],
    allow_smaller_final_batch=True
)

train_close = train_queue.close()



def RNN(inputs, reuse):
    with tf.variable_scope('cells', reuse=reuse):
        basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=batch_size, reuse=reuse)

    with tf.variable_scope('rnn'):
        outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

    fc_drop = tf.nn.dropout(states, keep_prob)

    logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc_drop, num_labels, activation_fn=None)

    return logits

#Training
with tf.name_scope("cost_function") as scope:
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=train_label_batch, logits=RNN(train_batch, reuse=None)))
    train_step = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(cost)


cost_summary = tf.summary.scalar("cost_function", cost)
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir)

#Session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord, start=True)

    step = 0
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        sess.run(enqueue_train)
        for batch in range(num_batch):
            if step % 100 == 0:
                summary_str = cost_summary.eval(feed_dict={keep_prob: 1.0})
                file_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
            else:
                sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={keep_prob: 0.5})
            step += 1
    sess.run(train_close)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

    file_writer.close()
```

Comment: Did you check the accuracy? Is it better than random guessing? Is it improving? Which values do you achieve? If your accuracy is ok, then the loss might be just a remnant of your model being not able to describe the data perfectly, in particular the random fluctuations of the data.

Comment: The accuracy is 5%, so pretty bad. It is slightly better than just guessing, which is around 1%. I'm assuming this model doesn't learn well.

Comment: Ok, in this case you will probably have to face the question whether the correlation between the data and the targets is strong enough that your network will learn more than randomly. This is sometimes really hard to answer, but you might get some hints by comparing the number of variables in the training set (n_features * number_of_training_samples) with the degrees of freedom of you network, i.e. the trainable variables.

Comment: Right, the case is that, similarly, I'm writing several models to train with this data set, two of them works pretty well. This RNN and another two models got exactly the same accuracy. I posted the other models here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660450/tensorflow-vgg16-and-googlenet-not-converging). Since they all fluctuate around the same cost and returned the same accuracy (almost the same). So I started to think was it because of the input problem. But the same pipeline worked well with several other models.

Comment: Ok, this might be a problem. But I am not familiar enough with this stuff, so I cannot help you, unfortunately. Good luck for your search for the error!